# deriving Stokes' theorem from substituting this identity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

As per requested: deriving Stokes' theorem from substituting this identity

Making substitution with

> $ ∇ \times(\phi a) $

where $\phi$ is a scalar field, and $a$ is a vector field. Given that the identity is equal to:

$ ∇ \times(\phi a) = \phi (∇ \times a) + (∇\phi)\times a$

then derive stokes theorem:

$\int_{C}\phi dr = \iint_{S}n \times (∇\phi )dS$

for a surface $S$ with unit normal $n$ that is bounded by the closed curve $C$ , where the direction of $n$ obeys the usual convention.

What I've tried:

following from the hint

$$\nabla \times (\phi \mathbf{a}) \cdot \mathbf{n} = (\nabla \phi \times \mathbf{a})\cdot \mathbf{n} = (\mathbf{n} \times \nabla \phi) \cdot \mathbf{a}$$

substituting this into the theorem above gives,

$\int_{C} \phi \cdot \mathbf{a} dr=\iint_{S} (\mathbf{\hat{n}}\times\nabla\phi)\cdot\mathbf{a}dS$

Then taking out the constant **a**

$\mathbf{a}\cdot(\int_{C}\phi dr)=\mathbf{a}\cdot(\iint_{S}\mathbf{\hat{n}}\times(\nabla\phi)dS) $

since a is arbitrary we deduce that:
$\int_{C}\phi dr = \iint_{S}n \times (∇\phi )dS$

Comment: Try including the question in the body instead of just the title, I was like "so what's your question?

Comment: No, it's just I was reading the text and I was on the verge of flagging it for not being a question, and then I realized that it was in the title. I'm afraid that others might just close your question.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @jlammy I need a kick-start, so something to provide me with a foundatiom from which I can work from.

Comment: Using $∇ \times(\phi a) = \phi (∇ \times a) + (∇\phi)\times a$ is a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If  $\mathbf{a}$ is an arbitrary constant vector, then

$$\nabla \times (\phi \mathbf{a}) \cdot \mathbf{n} = (\nabla \phi \times \mathbf{a})\cdot \mathbf{n} = (\mathbf{n} \times \nabla \phi) \cdot \mathbf{a}$$

Comment: Can you have a look at my effort? and possibly correct me where I may have gone wrong

Comment: @na_'j'-lime:  That is the right idea.  I would not say "substituting into the theorem above"  though- - since there is none other than the conclusion you are trying to prove.  I would say applying Stokes' theorem, $\int_S(\mathbf{n} \times \nabla \phi )\cdot \mathbf{a} \, dS = \int_S \nabla \times (\phi \mathbf{a}) \cdot \mathbf{n} \, dS = \int_C \phi \mathbf{a} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$.  The $d\mathbf{r}$ should be the differential of a vector. Then you can take $\mathbf{a}$ outside, etc.

Comment: What you are deriving here is a variation of Stokes' theorem.